# How to decode below json using php

Tags: php, json

How  to decode the json string below using php

```
$json = '{"keys":{"1":"Malayalam","2":"Hindi","3":"English","4":"Tamil"}}';
```

when i apply

```
<?php
     print_r(json_decode($json));
?>
```

It resulted

like

```
stdClass Object ( [keys] => stdClass Object ( [1] => Malayalam [2] => Hindi [3] => English [4] => Tamil ) )
```

How can i extract the language name independently.

Comment: You read manual: http://php.net/json_decode right?

Comment: These **are** independent names. You can access them individually using `foreach`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with:

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$languages = $data['keys'];
```

Now in `$languages` you will have the wanted part from the json.

Answer (score 1):

```
$json = '{"keys":{"1":"Malayalam","2":"Hindi","3":"English","4":"Tamil"}}';
$d = json_decode($json);

echo $d->keys->{'1'} . "\n";
echo $d->keys->{'2'} . "\n";

$key = '3';
echo $d->keys->{$key} . "\n";
```

Comment: you could be more explicit... where does this `$d` comes from ?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<?php
$json = '{"keys":{"1":"Malayalam","2":"Hindi","3":"English","4":"Tamil"}}';
?>
<pre>
<?php
$str = json_decode($json, true);
$keys = $str["keys"];
var_dump($keys);
foreach($keys as $key)
 echo $key . "\n";
?>
</pre>
```

output:

```
array(4) {
  [1]=>
  string(9) "Malayalam"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "Hindi"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "English"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "Tamil"
}
Malayalam
Hindi
English
Tamil
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$json = '{"keys":{"1":"Malayalam","2":"Hindi","3":"English","4":"Tamil"}}';
$json_dec = json_decode($json);

foreach ($json_dec->keys as $key){
   echo $key;
}
```

Comment: This does not answer OP question. Also -1 for no code block brackets - that's bad habit.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski, ya you are right, It is bad habit but not wrong for one line statement in foreach loop.  but why down vote ?  solution is perfect, we suggest him to edit but down vote is not right reward for solution.